# Google Calendar API - Recurring Events - GDATA - iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I am trying to build an app which shows events from a google calendar. I am using GData. Does any of you know how can I modify GDataQueryCalendar or other things such that google calendar doesn't show recently edited recurring event twice.

For Eg: If I have a recurring event called 'Breakfast' which is repeated daily at 7am. When I check the feed it shows the event only once. But, if I go back and edit the event's title to 'Breakfast1' only for today. And then when I check the feed it shows two events. One is "Breakfast" at 7am and the other one is "Breakfast1" at the same time 7am. Starttime on both the events are same.

How can I get the event only for that day (Breakfast1 as in eg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.. I am checking if a GDataEntryCalendarEvent event has an original event with it ([event originalEvent]). If an event has original event then we need to use this event instead of the duplicate event.